# How can I find elements including certain strings in id with selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was working on some simple crawler to **scrape** retweet counts on Twitter.
And I'm stuck with this:

```
<span class="ProfileTweet-actionCountForAria" id="profile-tweet-action-retweet-count-aria-123456789123456789">리트윗 0개</span>
```

That's the targeted tags I want to collect. And you can see the id of the tag has some varying id number for each user. So I was trying to collect those with find_elements_by_xpath like this:

```
retweets = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@id='profile-tweet-action-retweet-count-area-*'].text")
```

I thought * worked in some places in selenium, but it doesn't work in that code.

So, in short, how can I find elements with id including 'profile-tweet-action-retweet-count-area'?

Thanks for your attention. I couldn't find the questions like this (maybe I didn't search it with the right question, hmm), but good references or other links are also found with me!

Comment: That's not how * works.

Comment: @cruisepandey Yeah I thought so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Css selector would be :

```
span[id*="profile-tweet-action-retweet-count-aria"]
```

or a way better css selector would be :

```
span[id^='profile-tweet-action-retweet-count-aria']
```

If you have multiple entries with that, you can use `find_elements` method which will give you **list** of **web element**.

If you don't want css selector and would want to stick with xpath :

```
//span[contains(@id,"profile-tweet-action-retweet-count-aria")]
```

**Code :**

```
list_retweet = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(@id,"profile-tweet-action-retweet-count-aria")]")

for retweet in list_retweet:
  print(retweet.text)
```

Comment: @JeongInKim : You should really check Ahmed answer, I don't think that would work for you.

Comment: I think in your code you have to use escape character or single quotation inside the contains method.

Comment: Doesn't matter, single and double both would work, depending how the compiler will take it.

Comment: Thanks again cruisepandey. It's strange that it can get list of elements, but it only prints blanks only when I try to print them out with .text ... hmm

<span blablabla>리트윗 0개</span> should print 리트윗 0개 with .text, right?

Comment: more span would have `profile-tweet-action-retweet-count-area-` as id and followed by some variable. So getting a list is not a strange thing.

Comment: Oh never mind! It worked with 'get_attribute('innerHTML')' . Thanks again cruisepandey. It wasn't a text... sorry for bother!

Comment: Your XPath can use [`starts-with()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/starts-with) instead of `contains()` to match the equivalent `^=` CSS selector.

Comment: @JeffC : yes, Thank you. I’ll change it straight once I’ll have access to my PC.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `contains()` or `starts-with()` method in xpath or css selector.

Also, to get the text from the element, you have to use the `.text` outside of the `find_element` method

**XPath:**

```py
retweets = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[starts-with(@id,'profile-tweet-action-retweet-count-area-')]")
```

Or,

```py
retweets = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(@id,'profile-tweet-action-retweet-count-area-')]")
```

**CSS Selector:**

```py
retweets = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span[@id^='profile-tweet-action-retweet-count-area-']")
```

Or,

```py
retweets = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span[@id*='profile-tweet-action-retweet-count-area-']")
```

You have to iterate the list to get all the element and then you can get the text of the element using `.text`

```py
for retweet in retweets:
    print(retweet.text)
```

---

**Edit:** As cruisepanday mentioned `find_elements_` returns a list and `.text` is not applicable. Also, the CSS selector shouldn't have the `//`. I've changed the code accordingly.

Comment: @S Ahmed : How can a list have `.text` method. List is in `python` and `.text` is in selenium ?

Comment: Thanks Ahmed! Thanks for the way to use it in css selector as well. I found that 
 both of those can't collect elements from hidden one, so I'm working on it right now.

Comment: That's a invalid css selector too. I'm surprised that OP has accepted your answer.

Comment: Even after edit, sadly your css selector is not correct.

Comment: @cruisepandey Thanks for catching the mistakes in my answer.

Comment: You should really update your answer, cause it's accepted now, if someone will come after sometime, they will be misjudged.

Answer (score 1):

Use `WebdriverWait` to handle dynamic elements Try following Xpath Or Css Selector

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//span[@class="ProfileTweet-actionCountForAria"][starts-with(@id,"profile-tweet-action-retweet-count-aria-")]')))
print(element.text)
```

OR

```
element1=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'span.ProfileTweet-actionCountForAria[id^="profile-tweet-action-retweet-count-aria-"]')))
    print(element1.text)
```

Please note that you need to use following imports.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: That's actually the one I can use in my other problem! Gee, Thanks a lot!